# Calling SQL Stored Procedure and Get Return as success or failed using sqlsrv in php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I've looked over several other questions that seem (from the titles) the same as this. However, my case is a bit different. I tried to everyway but still I am unable to get what I expect..... here is a little brief on what I tried...

**My MSSQL Table**

```
Use Testing
Go

If Exists (Select * From sys.objects Where object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test_Table') And type in ('U')) Drop Table dbo.Test_Table
Go

Create Table dbo.Test_Table(
    FirstName NVarchar(50) Not Null Default '',
    LastName NVarchar(50) Not Null Default '',
    Age Int Not Null Default 0,

    Constraint PK_Test_Table Primary Key Clustered (FirstName) With (Pad_Index=Off,Statistics_NoRecompute=Off,Ignore_Dup_Key=Off,Allow_Row_Locks=On,Allow_Page_Locks=On)
)
```

**My Stored Procedure**

```
Use Testing
Go

Set Ansi_Nulls On
Go
Set Quoted_Identifier On
Go

If Exists (Select * From sys.objects Where object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.SP_Test_Data') And type In ('P','PC')) Drop Procedure dbo.SP_Test_Data;
Go

Create Procedure dbo.SP_Test_Data
    @FirstName NVarchar(50) Out,@LastName NVarchar(50) Out,@Age Int Out
As
Begin
    Declare @status Int = 0;
    Begin Transaction
    Begin Try
        Insert Into Test_Table(FirstName,LastName,Age) Values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Age)
        If(@@Trancount > 0)
            Begin Commit Transaction;
            Set @status=1;
        End;
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        If @@Trancount > 0
            Begin RollBack Transaction;
            Set @status=0;
        End;
    End Catch
    Select Stat=@status,FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Age=@Age
    Return @status;
End;
Go
```

**Testing in MSSQL Management Studio**

```
Use Testing
Go

Declare @FirstName NVarchar(50) = 'John',@LastName NVarchar(50) = 'Doe',@Age Int = 43,@stat Int = 0;
Exec @stat = dbo.SP_Test_Data @FirstName Out,@LastName Out,@Age Out
```

This working absolutely fine, I am getting @stat = 1 after insert when insert is success and getting @stat = 0 when failed.

**My PHP Code**

```
<?php

    $ServerName = '.\MSSQL2008';
    $DBaseName  = 'Testing';
    $Output = array();
    
    $firstName  = 'John';
    $lastName   = 'Doe';
    $age        = 43;
    
    $sp_params = array(
        array($firstName, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
        array($lastName, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
        array($age, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
    );
    
    try{
        $Scon = sqlsrv_connect($ServerName);
        $RQS = "Exec ".$DBaseName.".dbo.SP_Test_Data @firstName=?,@lastName=?,@age=?";
        $RST = sqlsrv_prepare($Scon, $RQS, $sp_params);
        if(!sqlsrv_execute($RST)){
            $Output = array('status'=>'failed','type'=>'sql error','debug'=>$RQS,'result'=>$RST);
        }
        else{
            if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RST)){
                $Output = $row;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){$e->getMessage();}
    if(($errors = sqlsrv_errors())!= null){
        $Output = array('status'=>'failed','detail'=>$errors);
    }
    sqlsrv_close($ServerName);
    if(!empty($Output)){print_r($Output);}
?>
```

**PHP Output**
No matter if the procedure execute result is success or fail, I am getting same return in php

> Array ( [status] => failed [detail] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
> IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -28 [code] => -28 [2] => The active
> result for the query contains no fields. [message] => The active
> result for the query contains no fields. ) ) )

**What I expect**
I expect procedure executing result, when it succeed it return 1 and when failed return 0, and also I expect 1 or 2 column data value like 'FirstName' or 'Age' to ensure.

I tried a lot but failed, can anyone help me to figure out where I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, do not prefix your procedure names with `sp_`, the prefix is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. Using it comes at a performance penalty and could mean your procedure simply doesn't work after an update.

Comment: @Larnu, Thanks for the suggestion, I changed my Procedure name, but no change in output, it still same, I am not getting proper result

Comment: Try adding "set nocount on;" as the first statement in your procedure. And FWIW your stored procedure needs some serious attention. You have much to learn about writing effective, efficient TSQL and implementing stored procedures in an efficient manner - a very different question.

Comment: Your procedure has many issues, the explicit transaction is superfluous? the output parameters appear unused? why return the values that are already passed in...?

Comment: As already mentioned, add `set nocount on;` at the beginning of your stored procedure code. PHP throws the error *The active result for the query contains no fields* because of the *1 rows affected* message returned by the insert statement. PHP is expecting 1 row and some columns at this point, but none are present. The `set nocount off;` prevents this issue.

Comment: I added 'NoCount On' still no solution, the problem is same to me, can any one point out where is the wrong in my code, as said by @Stu, "the output parameters appear unused?", I think it's not, I used them as Select Stat=@status,FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Age=@Age